# plotting an sRGB gamut Chromaticity Diagram starting with xy coordinates

Tags: visible-light

Starting with `xy` coordinates I would like to plot a chromaticity diagram displaying just the sRGB gamut portion of the CIE xy chromaticity diagram.

For each `xy` coordinate of my diagram I need to determine the corresponding `Y` value to obtain the complete `xyY` representation, from which `XYZ` tristimulus values can be calculated and finally `sRGB` values derived.

By starting with the known sRGB `Red`, `Green`, `Blue` and `white` values: `#FF0000`, `#00FF00`, `#0000FF`, `#FFFFFF` respectively I can use the Bradford matrix to deduce their `XYZ` tristimulus values and thus their `xyY` representations.

But starting with `xy` coordinates is there a method for determining the `Y` component?

ps. If you are able to add new tags, could you possibly add some tags like 'colorimetry', 'chromaticity-diagram' and 'color-models'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Y` component is for you to choose, because for a given `x,y` pair, depending on `Y`, the colour **may or may not** lie within the sRGB volume.

It is possible to know whether there is at least one sRGB colour that will map to a given `x,y` pair, though. Note that if linear RGB values `(R,G,B)` are transformed to `(x,y,Y)`, then `(a*R,a*G,a*B)` are transformed to `(x,y,a*Y)`. Multiplying each of the RGB triplets with a constant doest not affect `x` or `y`.

So one way to take an `(x,y)` pair and find out whether it can be obtained from an sRGB value is:

- set `Y = 100`
- convert `(x,y,Y)` back to `(X,Y,Z)`
- convert `(X,Y,Z)` to linear RGB `(R,G,B)`
- if one of `R`, `G` or `B` is negative, we are **out of the sRGB space**
- otherwise, divide each of `R`, `G` and `B` by the largest of the three
- optionally, convert linear `(R,G,B)` to gamma-corrected sRGB values

Here is some GLSL code that does the job:

```
vec4 color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

vec3 xyY = vec3(pass_Position.xy, 100.0);
vec3 XYZ = xyY.z * vec3(xyY.x / xyY.y, 1.0, (1.0 - xyY.x - xyY.y) / xyY.y);

mat3 XYZtoRGB = mat3(vec3( 0.032406f, -0.009689f,  0.000557f),
                     vec3(-0.015372f,  0.018758f, -0.002040f),
                     vec3(-0.004986f,  0.000415f,  0.010570f));

vec3 RGB = XYZtoRGB * XYZ;

if (RGB.x >= 0.0 && RGB.y >= 0.0 && RGB.z >= 0.0)
{
    RGB /= max(RGB.x, max(RGB.y, RGB.z));
    vec3 sRGB = pow(RGB, vec3(1.0 / 2.4));
    color.xyz = sRGB;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: sRGB gamut]

Comment: Hi Sam! thank you very much for your answer. Sorry for the slow reply I'm still new to working with colour models and wasn't sure if I had more questions but I think I'm ok for now. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, this was incredibly helpful. I'd been trying to render something similar for quite a while and kept getting stuck on "I know what x and y are, but what should Y be?".  I made a codepen that renders this using an HTML canvas: https://codepen.io/bantic/pen/oyRXOX?editors=1010